# GIT hangs when pushing

Tags: git, push

When i try to push my code to git it just hang, no error messages just standing still.

```
Counting objects: 10, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 7.80 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
POST git-receive-pack (8124 bytes)
```

Searching the net I have seen people having problem with large repositories and when the data is chunked but the repository is small and the message is not "`POST git-receive-pack (chunked)`" so no chunk problem. Just to be sure I attempted to change buffer size to a big one with git config http.postBuffer 524288000, no difference. I have tried leaving it on over the night to see if anything happens but it just stands still like that.

Any suggestions for future troubleshooting would be much appreciated.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go)**

Comment: I often have such git "hanging" issues if my connection is unstable. Is your connection stable?